# Why PHP Curl execution time is increased while using php 7.3 and Nginx compare to Apache and php 5.6

Tags: php, apache, nginx, php-curl, php-7.3

I am using Apache and PHP 5.6 to execute a curl for an API hosted on another domain with a URL in the format of https://xyz. The total curl execution time for this setup is around 30 milliseconds. However, when I use this curl with a setup having Nginx and PHP 7.3, the execution time increases to 100-150 milliseconds. I used curl get info to obtain the following stats:

**With Apache and PHP 5.6:**

- **name lookup time**- ~4 milliseconds
- **connect time** - ~6 milliseconds
- **Pretransfer time**- ~14 milliseconds
- **Starttransfer time**- ~16 milliseconds
- **total time** - ~28 milliseconds

**With Nginx and PHP 7.3:**

- **name lookup time**- ~3 milliseconds
- **connect time** - ~4 milliseconds
- **Pretransfer time**- ~80 milliseconds
- **Starttransfer time**- ~80 milliseconds
- **total time** - ~100 milliseconds

Can someone suggest why this might be happening and what solutions exist to resolve this issue?

Comment: Are those results from the same machine? If not - are there any significant hardware differences between the two machines, you're testing on? Also if you're testing on different machines - are they in the same data center or in completely different locations?

Comment: Results are from different machines. Both machines are in the same location, specifically in the same AWS VPC under the same ALB. Both are 2 Core 8GB EC2 instances.